# how to add multiple files in Linker_Flag variable in scilab?

Tags: linux, scilab, toolbox

I am working with Scilab version 6.1.0 and OS is Ubuntu 18.04. I was working to add a toolbox to Scilab for an already existing library. I have interfaced two functions of library in Scilab separately. I am not able to interface them simultaneously. I think the reason is the Linker_Flag variable in file "builder_gateway_cpp.sce"
here are the contents of this file:

```
mode(-1)
lines(0)
toolbox_title = "test_toolbox";
Build_64Bits = %t;
path_builder = get_absolute_file_path('builder_gateway_cpp.sce');
Function_Names = [
        "get_random_gaussian","sci_get_random_gaussian","csci6";
        "colormap_jet", "sci_colormap_jet" , "csci6";
        ];   
//Name of all the files to be compiled
Files = [
                "source.cpp";
                "sci_get_random_gaussian.cpp";
                "sci_colormap_jet.cpp";
                ]
[a, opt] = getversion();
Version = opt(2);
if getos()=="Windows" then
    third_dir = path_builder+filesep()+'..'+filesep()+'..'+filesep()+'thirdparty';
    lib_base_dir = third_dir + filesep() + 'windows' + filesep() + 'lib' + filesep() + Version + filesep();
    inc_base_dir = third_dir + filesep() + 'windows' + filesep() + 'include';
    C_Flags=['-D__USE_DEPRECATED_STACK_FUNCTIONS__  -I -w '+path_builder+' '+ '-I '+inc_base_dir+' ']   
    Linker_Flag  = [lib_base_dir+"libraryname.lib "]

elseif getos()=="Darwin" then //Mac
    third_dir = path_builder+filesep()+'..'+filesep()+'..'+filesep()+'thirdparty';
        lib_base_dir = third_dir + filesep() + 'Mac' + filesep() + 'lib' + filesep() + Version + filesep();
        inc_base_dir = third_dir + filesep() + 'Mac' + filesep() + 'include' ;
        C_Flags=["-D__USE_DEPRECATED_STACK_FUNCTIONS__ -w -fpermissive -I"+path_builder+" -I"+inc_base_dir+" -Wl,-rpath "+lib_base_dir+" "]
        Linker_Flag = ["-L"+lib_base_dir+" -lmul -Wl,-rpath="+lib_base_dir]

else//LINUX

    third_dir = path_builder+filesep()+'..'+filesep()+'..'+filesep()+'thirdparty';
    lib_base_dir = third_dir + filesep() + 'linux' + filesep() + 'lib' + filesep() + Version + filesep();

    inc_base_dir = third_dir + filesep() + 'linux' + filesep() + 'include';

    C_Flags = ["-I"+inc_base_dir];

        Linker_Flag = ["-L" + lib_base_dir + " -lrand -Wl,-rpath="+lib_base_dir ]
end

tbx_build_gateway(toolbox_title,Function_Names,Files,get_absolute_file_path("builder_gateway_cpp.sce"), [],Linker_Flag, C_Flags,[]);

clear toolbox_title Function_Names Files Linker_Flag C_Flags;
```

you can see the variable Linker_Flag in else part where there is a link for "-lrand" file only which compiles "sci_get_random_gaussian.cpp" .Now , I also want to link for "-lcolormap_jet" file which compiles "sci_colormap_jet.cpp".
How should i do it?

Answer (score 0):

Linker_Flag = ["-L" + lib_base_dir + " -lcolormap_jet -lrand -Wl,-rpath="+lib_base_dir ]

Comment: By doing this, `exec builder.sce` command gets executed successfully but it gives error while executing `exec loader.sce`exec: error on line #19: "addinter: problem with one of the entry point."

Comment: did you test under the  different platforms ?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 18.04 only

Comment: Please make your whole toolbox dir available if you want me to help you.

Comment: how should I do it??